# Force Google Maps Javascript API to Lite Mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get zoom levels over 19 for locations in Istanbul/Turkey in Google maps JavaScript API v3. I can get zoom level up-to 23 in "ROADMAP" map type. However, when I change it to "HYBRID", I can only get max zoom level of 19. The same problem exits in Google Maps v3 also. As you can see in the links below I can't get the same zoom level in "Earth" mode, the map automatically zooms out when it's change from Map->Earth.

[A sample location in map mode](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Galata+Tower/@41.0256129,28.974211,21z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x14cab9e7a7777c43:0x4c76cf3dcc8b330b)

[The same location in earth mode](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Galata+Tower/@41.0255732,28.9742066,230m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x14cab9e7a7777c43:0x4c76cf3dcc8b330b)

I've found that by forcing Google Maps to open in Lite Mode it's possible to get zoom levels over 19 for the same location in Earth mode. 
So, is there a way to force Google Maps JavaScript API to load in Lite Mode, or how can I get zoom levels over 19 in HYBRID mode for such locations.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem as Google doesn't have such satellite images with proper resolutions in some points especially on very high zoom levels.

I suggest you to use [Maximum Zoom Imagery Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom).
This service returns the maximum zoom level at given point for satellite images. Therefore, you can use it as a reference for zoom level of *ROADMAP* type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can get satellite images on desired high zoom levels when using Google maps in Lite Mode as in this [link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Galata+Tower/@41.0255413,28.9742581,54m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x14cab9e7a7777c43:0x4c76cf3dcc8b330b)

Comment: API doesn't seem to contain such an option yet. I tried loading API with adding parameter `force=clear`, no luck.